# Object created twice in database on save()

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my class model:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='requests')
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, related_name='requests', null=True, blank=True)

    fare = models.OneToOneField(Fare, null=True, blank=True)

    REQUEST_STATE_CHOICES = ((0, 'NEW'), (1, 'PROCESSING'), (2, 'SUCCEED'), (3, 'FAILED'))
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=REQUEST_STATE_CHOICES, default=0)
    express = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today())
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today())

    request_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    origin_lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    origin_lon = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    origin_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    destination_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    NB_DRIVERS_AROUND = 10

    @staticmethod
    def createRequest(client, originLat, originLon, originAddress, destinationAddress, requestDate=None, driver=None):
        """
        Create request
        :param client: the client
        :param originLat: origin latitude
        :param originLon: origin longitude
        :param originAddress: origin address
        :param destinationAddress: destination address
        :param driver: driver, default=None
        """
        request = Request()
        request.client = client
        request.origin_lat = originLat
        request.origin_lon = originLon
        request.origin_address = originAddress
        request.destination_address = destinationAddress
        request.driver = driver
        if driver is not None:
            request.express = False

        if requestDate is None:
            request.request_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        else:
            request.request_date = requestDate

        request.save()
```

When I call Request.createRequest(...) from the views, two objects are created into the database (I checked my admin and my database). When I call it via `manage.py shell` only one Request object is created as expected. I am using Django 1.6 and postgresql

Here is the call via `views`:

```
def test(request):
    client = Client.objects.get(username='brams')

    Request.createRequest(client, 36.822718, 10.15789, 'Rue 6449, el omrane', 'le kram',   requestDate=None,driver=None)

    return render(request, 'test.html', {})
```

Here is the call via `manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from etaxi_prod.models import Request, Client
>>> Request.objects.all()
[]
>>> client = Client.objects.get(username='brams')
>>> request = Request.createRequest(client, 36.822718, 10.15789, 'Rue 6449, el omrane',     'le kram', requestDate=None, driver=None)
>>> request
<Request: Request object>
>>> Request.objects.all()
[<Request: Request object>]
>>>
```

**Do you know why?** (I already spent hours checking the Django documentation and issues and found nothing)

Comment: How have you determined that duplicates exist?  Can you replicate this using `manage.py shell` and calling createRequest manually?  I see that you've got created/modified fields using datetime.datetime.today().  Shouldn't these be default=datetime.datetime.today. ie a callable?

Comment: Actually calling the save method from the shell creates only one object as expected. But when I use it via views, it creates two objects. See above the edited answer

Comment: Your view is being called twice. Check your access log.

Comment: Could stick a breakpoint onto the Request save method and debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are some "create"-related events floating around which call your createRequest as well?

You could use django debug toolbar to see all events and it helps inspecting your variables as well (e.g. you could set logging messages in your view and check whether it's called twice).